# Spring - import jpa repositories from another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-repositories

I have two gradle modules: `common` and `app`

The `common` module contains a JpaRepository named `OutboxJpaMessageRepository`.

The `app` module contains another JpaRepository named `RentRepository`.

The `common` has the following configuration class, which is auto-imported by the other module (using a `spring.factories` file):

```java
@Configuration
@EntityScan("path.to.common.module")
@EnableJpaRepositories("path.to.common.module")
@ComponentScan("path.to.common.module")
public class OutboxMessagingAutoConfig {
}
```

The problem is that `@EnableJpaRepositories("path.to.common.module")` overrides the default auto-configuration of the application, and the app can't find `RentRepository` (different package).

Can a library exports jpa repositories without override the default configuration of the client?

I don't want to re-configure all apps which use the common module

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions I can think of:

- 1: @EnableJpaRepositories accepts an array as parameter, pass it path.to.app.module.
- 2: Use @EnableAutoConfiguration and spare yourself a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The `boot` module must contain multi path lick this:

> @ComponentScan({"path.to.common.module", "path.to.app.module"})

Answer (score 0):

I found [the solution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8134#issuecomment-276492150) to my problem.

I solved using `@AutoConfigurationPackage`

```java
@Configuration
@AutoConfigurationPackage
@ComponentScan("path.to.common.module")
public class OutboxJpaMessagingConfig {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using package list as argument, in both `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`. It works fine (Spring Boot v2.2.5.RELEASE):

```java
@Configuration
@EntityScan({ "my.common.entity", "my.app.entity" })
@EnableJpaRepositories({ "my.common.repository", "my.app.repository" })
public class ExampleConfiguration {

}
```

Did not see @Knewbit's answer before posting sorry seems redundant now.